# Using Microsoft Graph Explorer to fetch AD users and get Delta changes

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft Graph Explorer to test the delta user functionality. As per documentation, I should expect next link response for each request until we navigate all  users. In final response, we should get delta link. But I don't get delta link in the last response. Has anyone got success in using Microsoft Graph API to fetch Delta changes? This works fine with Azure AD Graph library but not with new Microsoft Graph API to fetch delta users.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the beta endpoint if you are not already. The delta feature is still in preview.

The URL is `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta`.

I'm getting an `@odata.deltaLink` property on the last page of results there.